# PVC not Accepted by CISCO 878

Tags: cisco, router, mpls, atm

I have the following config. set up for an MPLS network on my CISCO 878:

```
Current configuration : 941 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname MyHost
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
resource policy
!
ip subnet-zero
ip cef
!
!
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
controller DSL 0
 mode atm 
 line-term cpe
 line-mode 2-wire line-zero
 dsl-mode shdsl symmetric annex B
 line-rate auto
!         
!         
!         
!         
interface BRI0
 no ip address
 encapsulation hdlc
 shutdown 
!         
interface ATM0
 ip address 10.120.240.152 255.255.255.252
 no atm ilmi-keepalive
 pvc 0/95 
  cbr 2048
 !        
!         
interface FastEthernet0
!         
interface FastEthernet1
!         
interface FastEthernet2
!         
interface FastEthernet3
!         
interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.22.33.1 255.255.255.0
!         
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.120.240.151
!         
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!         
!         
control-plane
!         
!         
line con 0
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login    
!         
scheduler max-task-time 5000
end
```

Now, the only problem that I had setting those parameters was PVC.
I'm supposed to set:

```
 pvc 42/95
```

But it doesn't accept!
Please have a look at this configuration to see where I have gone wrong.
When I use the help, it says VPI can't be more than 35.
I used `pvc 0/95`, but it doesn't work when I install the router.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the maximum supported PVC's for a device by checking the output of `show atm interface ATM0`. I suspect you will be limited to 4 VC's with a maxiumum of 1024 VCI's per VPI. If this is the case, your hardware doesn't support the maximum 8 bit VPI ATM header that would allow for a maximum VPI of 255.

This is going to be a hardware limitation of the ATM Controller itself. You can confirm this by checking your hardware against https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/asynchronous-transfer-mode-atm/permanent-virtual-circuits-pvc-switched-virtual-circuits-svc/24871-maxvp-vc-3-24871.html